# Does math.stackexchange provide any tool for users to download questions in bulk.

Tags: support, export

Few years ago, when I did not have an account on this website, I used to note question id in my notebook for future reference to the question( I did not have a personal computer so there was no option to bookmark things and all, and also I did not know about the fact that I can save bookmarks online etc)

Now it is too tiring for me to type question id each time I want to access those question.

Is there an API kind of thing(as Facebook and Twitter have) using which I can download the question I want, by writing a small code or something like that?

I mean does math.stackexchange provide any tool for users to download questions in bulk.

I am sorry if my question doesn't make any sense. Thank you

Edit: By question id, I mean the unique number associated with each question in the URL

eg: 3155081

will correspond to [How to find a counterexample for the following problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155081/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @YuiTo for editing the grammatical errors:)

Comment: It's not me. It's Grammarly. (but I'm not a salesperson!)

Comment: By downloading questions *in bulk* you mean that you have list of ids and you want to download all of the corresponding questions? Or do you mean something like downloading all questions from a given day, or in a given tag, or some other criteria?

Comment: I have a list of question ids and I want to download the corresponding questions. @MartinSleziak

Comment: Not exactly the same, but perhaps from these posts some inspiration can be obtained. (I hope that somebody will suggest a better solution.) [What is the best way to download a list of stack exchange questions for offline browsing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297520) and [How do I backup my Stackexchange favorites for offline use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158546)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks

Comment: Related (on Meta Stackexchange): [Where are the Stack Exchange data dumps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-are-the-stack-exchange-data-dumps) and its linked/related posts.

Comment: When you have time you can stop by in the room dedicated to Addons and Scripts. I have at least mentioned there some partial solutions I am able to suggest: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90615/conversation/list-of-question-links-from-a-list-of-id-s Maybe we might be able to figure out something which might work for you with the tools you have at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I really appreciate that :) @MartinSleziak

Answer (score 2):

## Choice of technologies

Since [SE API](//api.stackexchange.com/) gets real-time data, while [SEDE](//s.tk/data) returns data several days ago, the former will be used.

It's better to write a [web solution with AJAX](https://www.copterlabs.com/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/), but since I'm not a web developer (even though I maintain the [public GitLab instance](https://staticman3.herokuapp.com/) of [Staticman](https://staticman.net/) for [comments support on static sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users)), I'll use command line utilities in Unix shell as well as [Python's `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json.tool) (ships with [Python](https://www.python.org/)).

## Fetch multiple users' favorite questions

I'll use OP's and my favorite questions as an example.

```
USERS="581242;290189"
curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/$USERS/favorites?order=desc&sort=activity&site=math" | \
gzip -d | python -m json.tool > temp.json

awk 'BEGIN {
  print "  QID   |   Title   "
  print " ------ | ---------"
  ORS = ""
}
/question_id/ && match($2, /[0-9]+/) {
  print sprintf("%7i", substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH)) " | "
}
match($0, "title\": \".*") {
  print substr($0, RSTART+9, RLENGTH-11) "\n"
}
' temp.json
```

Explanation of the above commands:

1. Define a list of `USERS` separated by `;`

   - at most 100 users is allowed here since that's the limit of `{ids}` in the API method below
   - in case of multiple users, wrap the input with a pair of `"`'s, so that the shell would *not* interpret the last user ID (UID) as a shell command
   - *no* whitespaces  are allowed around `=`
2. Send the user list to [SE API](//api.stackexchange.com/)'s [`/users/{ids}/favorites`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users) method with `{ids}` set to `USERS` so as to get a *gzipped* list of questions starred by any user in the list.

   - The URL is too long, so I break it with `\`.
   - The [API](//api.stackexchange.com/)'s response is compressed with [Gzip](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/), so *don't* directly display the output to avoid messing up your shell.
   - The results are sorted by activity in descending order in terms of timestamp.
   - Only the first 30 questions are returned.  See "paging" below.
3. Pipe the downloaded response to `gzip -d` for decompression.  You would get a *single-line* raw JSON *without* trailing newline `\n`.
4. [Pretty print the raw JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37059829/3184351) using the command line interface of [Python's `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json.tool), and redirect the standard output (STDOUT) to the file `temp.json`.

   - Make sure that `temp.json` *doesn't* exist before running this command because it'll be overwritten by the output of the Python's JSON tool.
   - I prefer saving it into a file instead of pipes so that you may reuse (other parts of) the data in the future.
5. The key extraction step: [AWK](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk)

   Basically, an AWK program is a (sequence of) `pattern {action}` running on each record.  By default, records are delimited by newlines `\n`. (`RS`: record separator)

   `pattern` can be

   - `/regex/` (as in [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html));
   - `/start/,/end/` (as in [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)); or
   - omitted (applies to each record).

   The most basic `{action}` is `{print}`, which print the current record to STDOUT.
   Each record has different fields, separated by  by default. (`FS`: field separator)

   - `{print $1}` prints the 1st column;
   - `{print $2}` prints the 2nd column; and so on
   - `{print $NF}` prints the last column; (`NF`: number of fields)
   - `{print $0}` prints the whole record.

   In this section, I keep the default `RS` (`\n`), so each line is treated as a record.  What my AWK script does:

   1. Print table header.
   2. Set `ORS` (output record separator) to empty `""`.

      - Since in `temp.json`, `question_id` and `title` are put into *different* lines, different `pattern`s and `{action}`s are needed.  The output of different `{action}`s are treated as different records.  However, in the table, QID and title are in the *same* line, so `ORS` *can't* be the default newline `\n`.
      - I tried setting `ORS = " "`, but the left alignment of the first line under the table header *didn't* match that of the rest.
   3. Find the line matching `question_id` and print only the QID and the output table column border `|`.

      - `$2` means the 2nd "column" (delimited by  by default)
      - `match($0, /pat) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}` returns [only the matched string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49085630/3184351)  Note that this works regardless of leading whitespaces  on the left-hand side since `RSTART` is a relative index.
      - `&&` means AND in logic.
      - `sprintf("%7i", string)` returns a string formatted as an integer taking at most seven characters in width.
   4. Perform a similar match for `title`.

      - Note the shifts `+9` and `-11`.
      - This works since colons `:` in post title will be escaped by backslash `\`.
      - Print newline '\n' at the end to start a new output table row.
   5. Paging (optional)

      - You may add the parameter `pagesize` ranging between `0` and `100` and it defaults to `30`

        ```
        https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/$USERS/favorites?pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&site=math
        ```
      - You may use `page` to switch between pages.  It defaults to `1`.  It's possible to write a `while`/`for`-loop to grab the entire list of favorite questions, but I left that as an exercise.

Output (first 30 questions )

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5928  100  5928    0     0  12532      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12506
  QID   |   Title   
 ------ | ---------
3210162 | Minimal polynomial of extension of degree 2 over a finite field with characteristic 2
3210220 | Prove that there is no group $G$ s.t. $\\operatorname{Aut}(G)=\\mathbb{Q}$
3187120 | O is a point in triangle ABC. OA, OB and OC are joined and produced to meet BC, AC and AB at D, E and F. Find the value of OD/AD+OE/BE+OF/CF.
 223851 | Parallelogram identity in the wave equation
 222237 | Irreducible polynomial means no roots?
 337937 | Why $\\sum_{k=1}^{\\infty} \\frac{k}{2^k} = 2$?
3206789 | $f : \\mathbb{R} \\to \\mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable such that $f(0)=0, f(1/n)=0 \\forall n\\in \\mathbb{N}$ show that $f&#39;&#39;(0)=0$
3201343 | Book questions on supremum, bounds.
3202967 | Baby Rudin 2.17
1576885 | Let $f: \\Bbb R \\to [0,\\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $g(x)=(f(x))^2$ is uniformly continuous. Which of the following is always true?
    477 | Cardinality of set of real continuous functions
  30732 | How can I evaluate $\\sum_{n=0}^\\infty(n+1)x^n$?
2047606 | Comparing the rank of the product of two matrices with the ranks of the factors
1845542 | Irreducible polynomial over $\\mathbb{Q}$ implies polynomial is irreducible over $\\mathbb{Z}$
      3 | List of interesting math podcasts?
3196648 | Can I say $1/x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0, \\infty)$ because it is not defined when x = $0$?
3195512 | which of following option is correct for heat equation (CSIR june 2018)
3194826 | Are the endpoints of the domain of a function counted as critical points?
2049398 | How to plot a SDE $dx(t)=Ax(t)dt+Bx(t)dW(t) $ using Matlab, and how will the graph look like?
3193758 | If $AB=-BA$ then do $A$ and $B$ share a common eigenvector?
3193315 | Zeros of $ f&#39;&#39;$
3193209 | Prove that $y_1=y_2$ or $\\{x \\in [a,b] \\mid y_1(x)=y_2(x)\\}$ is finite
3192961 | Suppose $f : [0, 1] \\to [0, 1]$ is differentiable such that $|f&#39;(x)|\\ne1$ for all $x\\in[0, 1]$. Prove $\\exists !a,b\\in[0,1]:f(a)=a,f(b)=1-b$
 325149 | Number of socks to guarantee getting a matching pair.
3191747 | Proving $\\lim _{n\\to\\infty}\\frac{1}{ a_n} \\neq \\alpha$ given $\\lim _{n\\to\\infty}a_n = 0$ and...
3190717 | Regarding steady state solution of $u_{t}= c^2 u_{xx}$ with $u_{x}(0,t) = c_{1}$ and $u(L,t) = c_{1}$?
3189897 | Proof-Verification: $ \\int_a^b \\left(\\frac{b-x}{b-a}\\right)^{2018}f(x)\\,{\\rm d}x \\leq \\frac{1}{2019}\\int_a^b f(x)\\,{\\rm d}x$
3190601 | Limit as $x \\to 0$ of $\\big(x \\int_x^1{\\frac{f(t)}{\\sin^2(t)}}\\: dt\\big)$
3190518 | Find $\\lim_{ n \\to \\infty} \\frac{e^{-n}}{\\sqrt{n}} \\sum_{k=0}^\\infty \\frac{\\sqrt{k+ n }}{k!} (n+a)^k$
3188674 | Maximum value of $|Z_1-Z_2|^2 +|Z_2-Z_3|^2+|Z_3-Z_1|^2$
```

## Batch download from Stack Printer

[Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/) prints SE questions into HTML files.

Suppose that the table obtained in the previous section is saved into a file `temp.txt`.  To extract a list of QID, the first two lines (table header) are ignored by the pattern `NR > 2`, where `NR` means current number of record.  We mainly focus on the first column (field) `$1`.  This is the *same* has having a list of QID without post titles (, which are in the 2nd column `$2` in `test.txt`).  We will [prepend and append strings](https://tio.run/##XY5BS8NAEIXv/RXDUjyVpiSiRggFRUUQEUW8FGFMp83S7G7cmU0qtb89bqyCeJjLPL7vPew2fX9xdXN7vxsBXD8VaqEmC/X5Gm@hxio@35Dp@fGuUJVIc54kXddNWbDcNF5bIT8tnUlo2zgv8/dALNrZYgAb9GgKdcTkW11SYVCqA0nbskK7JjXaj3bfmt8WGKcHbt/3Kj1JZ8ezXE3UpQtDFW3RNDUxcOU6bddgUYLHGpZkWcsHaAbrBBAMIQcfC6Ikz7I0i5KXiiyIg8AEZTChRtEtgXHtoMKWPK4JWo4466HnXzQfbKdZnp@l0fbg3TKUwuBWEGrxuNJ1nBhpu4TmT/gzhdUX) using AWK in order to convert QID `2620409` to Stack Printer URL

```
http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=2620409&service=math.stackexchange
```

Here's my actual command for batch downloading.

```
awk '              
BEGIN {
  baseURL="http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question="
  param="\&service=math.stackexchange"
} 
NR > 2 {
  system("wget " baseURL $1 param " -O " $1".html && sleep $(( ( RANDOM % 3 ) + 1 ))")
}' temp.txt
```

As usual, the constants are set in `BEGIN {...}`.  This is *not* necessary, but I prefer setting them at the beginning so that the code can be easily adapted and reused later.

`param` represents the parameters for this HTTP GET request.  I've found out that the leading ampersand `&` in `param` needs to be escaped by trial and error.  Perhaps it's because ampersand `&` makes jobs run in background in Unix shell.

The download action is executed from the third line.  The shell command is supposed to be

```
wget http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question={qid}&service=math.stackexchange -O {qid}.html
```

The utility `wget` downloads the SE question (specified by paramters`question` and `service`) to a file.  Without the option `-O`, the saved file name would default to the entire substring after the last slash `/` in the request URL.  Since filenames like

```
ls
...
'export?question=1576885&service=math.stackexchange'  'export?question=3&service=math.stackexchange'
'export?question=1845542&service=math.stackexchange'  'export?question=477&service=math.stackexchange'
...
```

are *undesirable*, we need something like `-O {qid}.html` so that the GUI file explorer will recognise that it's an HTTP document to be opened in a web browser.

The above `wget` command has to be adapted and called inside the AWK script by the action `{ system(...) }`.  This is as simple as wrapping the `wget` command by double quotes `"` and leaving AWK's variables outside the `"`'s.  Note that the double-quoted spaces  control the spaces in the `wget` command called, whereas the un-double-quoted spaces  *don't* matter.

Last but not least, I've introduced a brief random pause lasting for 1/2/3 second(s) for [friendly crawl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25909799/3184351).  After having written the above code block, I realized there's no need to reinvent the wheel.  `wget` has already provided options `--wait=10 --random-wait` and `--input-file=url.txt`.  I'm leaving these as an exercise.

## Remarks:  Failed `sed` + `xargs` way

I *don't* know a simpler way to get it done by `sed` + `xargs`.

```
sed -ne '3,$s/^\s*//p' temp.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | \
sed -e 's/^/https:\/\/www.stackprinter.com\/export?question=/' \
-e 's/$/\&service=math.stackexchange/' | xargs wget ???
```

The `sed` way gets complicated when you need to repeat the column {qid} twice for specifying `wget`'s output file name with `wget {baseURL}{qid}{param} -O {qid}.html`.  Once you know `awk`'s intuitive `{ print "foo " $3 " bar " $1, $3 }`, you *won't* want to spend your time escaping the slashes `/` in `sed`'s `s` command.